# Derivatives of functions defined implicitly

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions of one real variable and define $F(x,y)=f[x+g(y)]$. Find the formulas for the partial derivatives of $F$ of first and second order, expressed in terms of derivatives of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Have you tried the chain rule?

Comment: no. i can't see how to apply it here.

Comment: The partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is pretty much the usual. With respect to $y$, instead, you have a situation $f(g(y))$...

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks!